# Why doesn't Strawberry Perl call my DllMain?

Tags: windows, perl, mingw, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to port [Win32::Setupsup](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aSetupsup), a rather crusty old C++-based module intended to work with Visual C++, to Strawberry Perl and the MinGW GCC that it uses.  I've pretty much got it working except for one thing.

The C++ part of the module has a `DllMain` function that runs some initialization code at `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and cleanup code at `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.  When I compile the module with Visual C++, that works fine.  But when I compile it with the MinGW GCC that Strawberry Perl uses, `DllMain` is never called.

I think the problem is just that `DllMain` is not properly identified as the DLL's entry point when compiled with `gcc`.  But I don't know how to fix that.

The work-in-progress is in [my GitHub repo for Win32::Setupsup](http://github.com/madsen/win32-setupsup).  While I use [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org) to manage releases, you don't actually need `dzil` to test it.  Just clone the repo, `perl Makefile.PL`, and `dmake test`.

Comment: Does [`extern "C"`](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c200306030033.51176.hg%40technosis.de%3e) help?

Comment: @ephemient, that did it! And it doesn't seem to bother Visual C++, either.  Write that up as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved);
```

in a C++ source file.  Because this is a C++ function, G++ mangles the name to something like `__Z7DllMainP11HINSTANCE__mPv@12`, and it cannot be found when the library is loaded.

To solve this, use `extern "C"`, either on the function declaration

```
extern "C"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved);
```

or in a block

```
extern "C" {
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved);
}
```

to ensure that the function is given C linkage (avoiding C++ name mangling).